# Laravel pagination with problems

Tags: laravel

i have a simple question as i do not know which line i should add into to get laravel pagination. (->paginate(5).

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $codeSearch = $request->get('code');
    $descriptionSearch = $request->get('description');

    //$tmp = Category::all()->toArray();
    $tmp = Category::where('code','like','%' .$codeSearch. '%')->where('description','like','%' .$codeSearch. '%')->get()->toArray();

    $category = array();
    foreach ($tmp as $key => $row) {
        $policy = Category::find($row['parent_id']);

        $tmpResult = new Category();
        $tmpResult->id = $row['id'];
        $tmpResult->code = $row['code'];
        $tmpResult->description = $row['description'];
        $tmpResult->parent_id = $policy['description'];
        $tmpResult->status = $row['status'];

        array_push($category, $tmpResult);
    }

    return view('category.index', compact('category'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 $tmp = Category::where('code','like','%' .$codeSearch. '%')->where('description','like','%' .$codeSearch. '%')->paginate(5);
```

In view

```
 @foreach($tmp as $tm)
    //whatever operation you like to do
 @endforeach
 {{$tmp->links()}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Paginate can't be called on the collection, so you have to run it on the query, by simply replace `->get()` with `->paginate(5)` like this

```
$tmp = Category::where('code','like','%' .$codeSearch. '%')
    ->where('description','like','%' .$codeSearch. '%')
    ->paginate(5)
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: erm i want to ask how to create the view pagination page

Comment: To display pagination controls, you simply have to insert `{{ $yourCollectionName->links() }}` into your view. ([laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#displaying-pagination-results))

Answer (score 0):

The following `->get(), ->first(), all()` get the results from the database and so does ->paginate(5), so I would suggest that you replace `->get()` with `paginate(5)` an you can get rid of `toArray()` because the result will be a collection with which you can use `foreach()` or get a value by index.

Answer (score 0):

As you need an array in your condition, then you can simply convert the final array into a collection object and use the pagination concept.

```
$items = [
            'item1',
            'item2',
            'item3',
            'item4',
            'item5',
            'item6',
            'item7',
            'item8',
            'item9',
            'item10'
            ];

        // Get current page form url e.x. &page=1
        $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

        // Create a new Laravel collection from the array data
        $itemCollection = collect($items);

        // Define how many items we want to be visible in each page
        $perPage = 1;

        // Slice the collection to get the items to display in current page
        $currentPageItems = $itemCollection->slice(($currentPage * $perPage) - $perPage, $perPage)->all();

        // Create our paginator and pass it to the view
        $paginatedItems= new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageItems , count($itemCollection), $perPage);

        // set url path for generted links
        $paginatedItems->setPath($request->url());

        return view('items_view', ['items' => $paginatedItems]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to have a relationship setup for a `Category`'s parent. Then you can load the parent when you retrieve the categories.

```
class Category extends Model
{
    ...
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(self::class);
    }
}
```

I feel like your search is probably trying to do an `OR WHERE`, search the `code` field for this value or the `description`:

```
$categories = Category::with('parent')
    ->where('code', 'like', '%' .$codeSearch. '%')
    ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' .$codeSearch. '%')
    ->paginate(5);
```

Then in your view if you want the parent category's description you can get it through the relationship:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    parent description: {{ $category->parent->description }}
@endforeach
```